# Fabric.js loadFromJSON assigned object to custom attributes not converted properly

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a small project wherein I connect objects with arrows. I assign these arrow lines to each rect/group to update its position whenever the rect/group is modified or moved to a different point. However, after applying undo and redo using serialization and loadfromjson, the canvas fails to recognize the arrowlines, thus, unable to apply setCoords().

This is where I assign the lines. sObj is the origin rectgroup, eObj is the end rectgroup

```
var line = new fabric.Line([centerX1, centerY1, centerX2, centerY2], {
  fill: 'black',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  selectable: false,
  evented: false,
});

mapCanvas.add(line);
line.setCoords();

let xDiff = centerX2 - centerX1;
let yDiff = centerY2 - centerY1;
var angle = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
var arrowHead = makeArrow(angle, centerX2, centerY2);

line.arrowHead = arrowHead;
mapCanvas.add(arrowHead);


//set lines 
sObj.startLines = sObj.startLines || new Array();
sObj.startLines[sObj.startLines.length] = line;

eObj.endLines = eObj.endLines || new Array();
eObj.endLines[eObj.endLines.length] = line;
```

Image [image: connected objects]

and

[image: how arrow follows the object]

if u hit undo, the endObject will return to its previous location.
However, if you move it the arrow will not follow anymore.
[image: like so]

Here's what I use on saving and restoring

```
//saving
state = JSON.stringify(mapCanvas.toJSON(["typeName", "data",
 "arrowHead", "startLines", "endLines"]));

//restore
mapCanvas.clear();
mapCanvas.loadFromJSON(state, function() {
  mapCanvas.renderAll.bind(mapCanvas);
}, function() {
  console.log(state);
});
```

This is where the error comes in

```
if (rectGroup.endLines) {
  rectGroup.endLines.forEach(function(el) {
    el.setCoords();

    //[from console] Uncaught TypeError: el.setCoords is not a function

    let xDiff = centerX - el.x1;
    let yDiff = centerY - el.y1;
    var angle = (Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180 / Math.PI) + 90;

    el.set("x2", centerX).set('y2', centerY);

    el.arrowHead.set("left", centerX).set('top', centerY);
    el.arrowHead.set("angle", angle);
    el.setCoords();
  });
}
```

Comment: your code snippet is broken, kindly fix it.

Comment: @ArvindMaurya the code snippet i used here are just fragments. its too long to paste all of it here, I'm sorry, its my first time to post a question

Comment: Check what is the value of `el`.

Comment: @Durga on assigning it as an endLine to the rectGroup, it looks like
`i {fill: "black", dirty: false, stroke: "black"...}`. However, on loading it from json it change into `{type: "line", version: "3.4.0", originX: "left"...}`, is there any difference?

Comment: i believe, it wasn't converted to an actual fabric object, but rather into just an ordinary object. I'm stuck

Comment: in the reviver parameters of `loadFromJSON`,check for startlines and endlines and use [enlivenObject](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.html#.enlivenObjects) and reassign it.

Comment: i think i got it. thanks @Durga